# Good Free/Open Source graphics library for C#

Tags: c#, open-source, directx, gdi+

Im looking for a good Open Source or Free library in C# using GDI+ or DirectX. I would rather like using GDI+ than DirectX. The idea is to be able to graphicate nodes from a graph, so all I need is drawing circles, arrows and pointers.. nothing fancy, I don't want to use highly overloading libraries.

Thanks to all!

[EDIT]

I understand what you all say, but perhaps I didnt explain myself. I know how to work with GDI++ or WPF, but these is the deal:

1. Im looking for a library that provides some extended functions allowing not just to draw, but to control the shape (drag around, etc..)
2. Im not very pro-WPF in this particular case, because is not an application relying much on UI and I just want to show the graph and allow to rearrange nodes, nothing fancy. I'll take a look on the link given anyways.

I hope now that those who thought this was a lame question get the point.

Thanks again

Comment: System.Drawing uses GDI+, WPF uses DirectX.  It is 3 feet in front of you :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could just use [WPF's Drawing support for shapes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms747393.aspx).  This is an incredibly useful, easy, and powerful means of doing retained mode graphics.

Otherwise, GDI+ is exposed via the [System.Drawing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.aspx) namespace in the Framework, and is fairly easy to use, as well.

Both of these options are nice in that they require no extra libraries - support for this exists direclty in the framework itself.

Comment: System.Drawing is exactly what I would suggest if it was not already built in :-)

Answer (score 1):

[NShape](http://code.google.com/p/nshape/)- GPL. In BETA. Maybe a bit too sophisticated for your use, but sounds like it meets all your requirements. 199EUR for commercial use, which is cheap compared to the competition.